# argument length is too big. How to chunk it up?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, arguments, command-line-arguments

I have this python code which will take a filename and set of offsets (comma separated) and will read the corresponding lines defined in the offsets.

```
do   
    python fileOffset.py /mnt/media1/file $offsets >> tmpfile
done
```

`$offsets` will provide the string which is comma separated which contain the filepointers ( 12,123,121134). This works fine until I get a very lengthy string of offsets which will throw a *argument list too long* error. As a solution I have written the following code which will split the offsets and call the fileOffset.py one for one offset.

```
IFS=', ' read -a array <<< $offsets
for element in "${array[@]}"
do 
    python fileOffset.py /mnt/media1/$file $element >> tmpfile
done
```

But this makes processing of the file very slow. How could I make it faster?

Comment: do everything in python since you are spawning a new python process for each element in `array`. If hat doesn't appeal to you, have a look at `xargs`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xargs`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs) :

```
IFS=', ' xargs read -a array <<< $offset
```

However, I'm with @FrederikPihil's comment: Use python at all as you are already spawning a python process on each iteration.

Comment: Will I still be spawning python processes at each iteration even if I use xargs? If yes what's the purpose of using xargs?

Comment: It will feed `read` multiple times with chunks of the argument list if the argument list gets too long

Comment: I tried using xargs then it's giving me a "xargs: argument line too long". Only thing changed is from length to line. Why is this?

Comment: How do you populate `$offset`?